# Sending raw XML using Savon 2

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I'm trying to use Savon to send requests to a webservice. The service I'm consuming requires nested namespaces, and I haven't figured out yet how to provide them on a request.

I've tried to craft the request by hand (with nokogiri, actually) and send the resulting xml:

```
client.call(:some_op, :message=>{:"op"=>"<elem/>"})
```

But savon escapes the string and sends `&lt;elem/&gt;`

How can I send raw xml without escaping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The call should look like this:

```
client.call(:some_op, xml: "<elem />")
```

Or if you just want to set one or multiple namespaces then create a client as follows (without WSDL):

```
client = Savon.client(
  :endpoint => 'http://www.example.com',
  :namespace => 'urn:core.example.com',
  :namespaces => { 'ns1' => 'http://v1.example.com',
                   'ns2' => 'http://v2.example.com' },
  :log => true,
  :log_level => :debug,
  :pretty_print_xml => true
)
```

The namespaces are a `Hash` parameter.

Comment: This works, but gets rid of all the SOAP structure: `<Envelope><Body><SomeOp>...`. Is there a way to retain it?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have it both ways :-). What exactly was your problem in the first place that prevents you from using Savon standard methods? There are methods to inject additional namespaces if you need to.

Comment: Basically, I have two different namespaces, one for the operation (`tns`) and another for all the fields inside the message (`a`). I've managed to retain the message namespaces on responses with `:strip_namespaces=>false` on the client, but I can't figure out how to send the namespace definitions on a request - the [request locals documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/locals.html) doesn't seem to mention namespace options

Comment: Ideally I'd like to not deal with namespaces on hashes at all and let Savon handle it from the WSDL, but I'm not sure if that's possible...

Comment: I edited my answer. You might want to change your question a bit :-). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to to create the client without the wsdl as you've shown! I've edited the question a bit to mention the namespace problems

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Savon internally uses the Gyoku Gem to convert ruby hashes to XML, and Gyoku will not escape hash keys ending with exclamation marks according to the documentation: https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku#special-characters

So this code works to get raw XML into the request while still using Savon to generate the envelope xml:

`client.call(:some_op, :message=>{:"op!"=>"<elem/>"})`