# SAVON passing XML as a request to wsdl and getting response as xml

Tags: ruby, web-services, savon

I have a third party application and output of this application is an request xml which needs to be passed in to webservice (WSDL)

I need to do integration testing where i will be getting this request xml.

how can i pass this request xml using savon in Ruby ?
is there anyother way where we can pass request xml and get the output in response xml

i tried using soapui and it works but i am looking for native ruby solution

Comment: client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'globalweather.wsdl', ssl_verify_mode: :none, ssl_version: :TLSv1)

response = client.call(:get_cities_by_country, xml: "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:web='http://www.webserviceX.NET'>  <soap:Header/>   <soap:Body>      <web:GetCitiesByCountry>         <!--Optional:-->         <web:CountryName>United states</web:CountryName>      </web:GetCitiesByCountry>   </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>")

this is working but if i want to use same request from XML /request.xml, how do i read it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending raw XML using Savon 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913449/sending-raw-xml-using-savon-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I found the answer and below is the code

Then (/^I test wsdl$/) do
    require 'savon'

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_file = File.read("/test.xml")

client = Savon.client(wsdl: '/globalweather.wsdl', ssl_verify_mode: :none, ssl_version: :TLSv1)

response = client.call(:get_cities_by_country, xml: xml_file)
puts response.to_xml
print response.to_xml
```

end

Comment: I think you can drop the `require 'nokogiri'` line.

Comment: yeah i use nokagiri for xml datadriven